# Embed Plotly Dash components in React

Tags: reactjs, plotly-dash

Good day.

I have done some visualizations with Plotly in Python, but I have very limited experience with Plotly Dash. I have a React app in which I want to embed Plotly Dash components that my colleague created in Python. Is there a way to do that?

I see that you can use React to make Dash components, but I have Dash components that I want to embed in my React app.

Is that possible?

Any and all assistance is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's a weird question, but to summarize it, no, you can't use a Dash component in React.

One thing that is very important to understand is that DASH COMPONENTS are REACT COMPONENTS.

So, reproducing a Dash component in React is very easy (mainly if you're using CSS classes in your project)... In the links below, you can better understand how the Dash components are created using React:
https://dash.plotly.com/react-for-python-developers
https://dash.plotly.com/plugins
https://dash.plotly.com/all-in-one-components

I hope that this can be useful to make you a better understanding... Let me know if something is not too clear;

Regards,
Leonardo

Comment: Weird posters unite, because I don't get it either. I understand that Dash uses React components which can be rendered in Python. I have a python application that does just that: it serves an application with its Flask server. What I'm trying to understand is how to do the same thing directly in React, i.e. instantiating the components using the same data by writing Javascript inside a React application. I presume this is impossible to "translate" directly since the Python script uses Pandas. Please explain it like I'm 5. Thank you.